# How to display tasks that are not "checked" on the other screen?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, random

I am looking at my code and wondering for 2 hours now without luck so I will ask for help here.

I have a button, when I press it, it displays a random item from the list view. The problem is I also have a check box on the list view with each item. I do not want it to (Shuffle through the items with the checkbox ticked) only to shuffle through the Task in the list view that are unchecked/unticked/are not done.

Here is my code

```
class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
  List<Task> _tasks = [
    Task(name: "item1"),
    Task(name: "item2"),
    Task(name: "item3"),

  ];

  UnmodifiableListView<Task> get tasks {
    return UnmodifiableListView(_tasks);
  }

  int get taskCount {
    return _tasks.length;
  }
// <<Here is the code that shuffles through list
  Future<String> rann() async {
    return (_tasks.toList()..shuffle()).first.name;
  }
 
  void addTask(String newTaskTitle) {
    final task = Task(name: newTaskTitle);
    _tasks.add(task);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void updateTask(Task task) {
    task.toggleDone();
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

In another script I have this one

```
class Task {
  final String name;
  bool isDone;

  Task({required this.name, this.isDone = false});

  void toggleDone() {
    isDone = !isDone;
  }
}
```

In another script file I have this code

```
        Padding(
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 0),
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: Provider.of<TaskData>(context).rann(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: Text(
                  "${snapshot.data}",
                  //softWrap: true,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  //textWidthBasis: TextWidthBasis.longestLine,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

In another script I have this one

```
class TasksList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final task = taskData.tasks[index];
            return TaskTile(
              taskTitle: task.name,
              isChecked: task.isDone,
              checkboxCallback: (checkboxState) {
                taskData.updateTask(task);
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Edit : I also forgot to include this part of code

```
class TaskTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final String taskTitle;
  final Function(bool?) checkboxCallback;
  final VoidCallback longPressCallback;

  TaskTile(
      {required this.isChecked,
      required this.taskTitle,
      required this.checkboxCallback,
      required this.longPressCallback});


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onLongPress: longPressCallback,
      title: Text(
        taskTitle,
        // at the bottom, it sets decoration of text if isChecked is true, if its not its null
        style: TextStyle(
            decoration: isChecked ? TextDecoration.lineThrough : null),
      ),
      trailing: Checkbox(
        activeColor: Colors.blue,
        value: isChecked,
        onChanged: checkboxCallback,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your description so much confusing please clear your query. First, you said,"I do not want it to show (Shuffle through the items with checkbox ticked)items that are already checked/ticked, how can I possibly do this?" and lastly you said, "I have no idea how to connect these to make it only shuffle through the non-checked lists."

Comment: Hi, Sorry yes quite confusing. I tried my best to correct it and explain it clearer, hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**updated:**

```dart
    class TaskData extends ChangeNotifier {
        List<Task> _undoneTasksShuffled = []

        // you don't need anymore the rann method() instead you should iterate over this listView           
        UnmodifiableListView<Task> get undoneTasksShuffled => UnmodifiableListView<Task>(_undoneTasksShuffled);

        @override
        void notifyListeners() {
            //this updates _undoneTasksShuffled every time you call notifyListeners
            _undoneTasksShuffled = _tasks.where((e)=> !e.isDone).toList()..shuffle();
            super.notifyListeners();
        }

        ...
    }
```

---

I think you only need to filter the results before get a random element. you need to modify your rann method for something like

```dart
//you don't really need a future method because you don't have async code
String rann() {
    final r = Random();
    final undoneTasks = _tasks.where((e)=> !e.isDone).toList();
    //this is for avoid RangeException on list. you can return any other thing
    if(undoneTasks.isEmpty) return '';
    // i think that you don't really need to shuffle whole list, you only need a random element
    return undoneTasks[r.nextInt(undoneTasks.length)].name;
}
```

i hope this solves your question

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your help it did work as I wanted!  --- What is the difference between the random and shuffle ? (I seem to have small issue, when I have only 3 items out of 10, it keeps picking 2 only, or sometimes it keeps repeating for 3 times in a row. Is there way to randomize it more so it wont repeat next time ? so when you randomize once next time is not the same but different.

Comment: When I use the shuffle code i had, it does randomize pretty well, when I use r.nextInt, when I have 3 items it only shows 2 answers and ignores the last one (I tried it for about +20 times and never showed the 3rd item)

Comment: Hi, about your second comment issue. i edited the answer i had a typo because r.nextInt method needs an int but is exclusive, such you don't need subtract 1 to the list length

Comment: the difference between Random.nextInt() and List.shuffle is than nextInt returns an random integer between 0 and the given integer and based in that random integer you can get a random element on that list meanwhile the shuffle method change the order of every element of the list what is inneficient because you are taken only the first element

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Makes sense to use random instead of shuffle. One question, what is the void NotifyListeners for and the new class that you have added with _undoneTasksShuffled ? Not sure what to use it for. I just changed the String rann() to what you have updated and it seems to be working as I want without the other code? Thanks